# Contradictory Results in autocorrelation tests

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

I have a time-series model, with stationary variables. Testing for outocorrelation hasn't been easy:
- a can't calculate DW stat because of my small number of observations;
- the GB test indicates that there is autocorrelation
- the Correlogram Q statistics tells me differently, indicating that there is no autocorrelation...

what can cause this contradictory results? how do i manage this?

Comment: Are the various results all bouncing around your cutoff for significance (ie, some p=.04, some p=.06)?

Answer (score -1):

Are you relying on statistical significance tests? That could lead to this result.

Your language makes me think you are relying on these, since you say "is" vs. "is not" autocorrelation. There is almost certainly *some* autocorrelation, and the question is not whether it is statistically significant or not, it is whether it is big enough to matter.

What were the effect sizes for the two tests?

Also, you should graph your data and **see** the autocorrelation.

Comment: the problem is that i need to rely in statistical significance tests since it is my thesis, and i can't find any other example of the same problem in the internet. How can i correct the autocorrelation?

Comment: i can't create an AR(1) model because of the limited amount of observations...

Comment: If you have so little data that you can't run an AR(1) model, then you probably don't have a data set suitable for time series.

But you haven't told us anything about your project at all, so there's no way for us to offer help.

Please read [How to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/)

Comment: I am conducting a Study on poverty and inequality in Portugal through an OLS regression, from 2002 to 2010 (which are the only years for available data)... i am in such a stressed moment that i don't even know how to ask the right questions.. but my big problem has to do with these contradictory test solutions on the matter... thank you for trying to help...

Comment: Have you considered a multi level model?

Comment: Why would i use a multi level model? i don't know that type of model...

Comment: MLMs are an extension of regression that allows for dependent data. Sounds ideal for your study, insofar as I understand it. 

Time series is not designed for cases with only 8 time periods.

Comment: Thnak you.. i'll research more on MLM's and see if i have time to do it... :)

Comment: I downvoted this because this seems more like a long comment than an answer and it seems like the clarification asked for in your **answer** should be requested before, not after answering.